# Fill dataframe is column name match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a df `df1` with N columns fill with value, another `df2` empty with M columns (M > N).
I have 2 lists representing all the columns name of `df1` and the matching columns name in the source `df2`, ordered.

Ex : `list1[0] -> list2[0]`

I could fill the data from `df1` to `df2` with a old for loop and I'm looking to do the same but in a more pythonic/pandas/functional way.

```
df1
    A   B   C   D
0   94  18  47  1
1   75  40  30  97
2   14  56  63  89
3   28  74  25  59
```

```
list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
list2 = ["Z1", "Z3", "Z4", "Z8"]
```

Expected output :

```
df2
    Z1  Z2  Z3  Z4  Z5  Z6  Z7  Z8
0   94      18  47               1
1   75      40  30              97
2   14      56  63              89
3   28      74  25              59
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is `rename` columns names by `dict` created by zip of columns and then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by columns names of second DataFrame:

```
df = df1.rename(columns=dict(zip(list1, list2))).reindex(df2.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   Z1  Z2  Z3  Z4  Z5  Z6  Z7  Z8
0  94 NaN  18  47 NaN NaN NaN   1
1  75 NaN  40  30 NaN NaN NaN  97
2  14 NaN  56  63 NaN NaN NaN  89
3  28 NaN  74  25 NaN NaN NaN  59
```

**Details**:

```
print (dict(zip(list1, list2)))
{'A': 'Z1', 'B': 'Z3', 'C': 'Z4', 'D': 'Z8'}

print (df1.rename(columns=dict(zip(list1, list2))))
   Z1  Z3  Z4  Z8
0  94  18  47   1
1  75  40  30  97
2  14  56  63  89
3  28  74  25  59
```

Comment: Awesome ! I forget that the args `columns` can take an iterable like a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# your code

df2 = df1.copy()
df2.columns = ["Z1", "Z3", "Z4", "Z8"]
df2["Z2"] = pd.np.NaN
df2["Z5"] = pd.np.NaN
df2["Z6"] = pd.np.NaN
df2["Z7"] = pd.np.NaN
```